# Using C# to perform common desktop search via Search Protocol

Tags: c#, desktop, windows-shell, windows-search

I'm trying to use C# to trigger windows common desktop search according to [windows search protocol](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144083(v=vs.85).aspx). It is very simple code to implement this.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const string searchQuery = "search:";
        Process.Start(searchQuery);
    }
```

Above works fine for both Win7 and Win8, a search window would show up. But when I add query as the document says:

```
    const string searchQuery = "search:query=a";
    Process.Start(searchQuery);
```

It just has no response, also no exception. Afterwards I tried to add location info in the query:

```
    const string searchQuery = "search:query=a&crumb=location:\\";
    Process.Start(searchQuery);
```

Strangely, this works fine for Win7, a search window prompt, and begin to search "a" as expected. But just failed in Win8 and has thrown an exection:

> Unhandled Exception: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The system
>   cannot fin d the drive specified
>   at
>   System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithShellExecuteEx(ProcessStartInfo
>   startI nfo)
>   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
>   at
>   System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
>   at
>   System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(String fileName)
>   at
>   ProcessStart.Program.Main(String[] args) in
>   e:\WorkSpace\ProcessStart\Proc essStart\Program.cs:line 15

What I have done wrong, and what's the difference between Win7 and Win8 about the search protocol? Thank you!

Comment: I found "search:query=a" works fine in some Win7, has default location same as search in Start Menu. I'm just confused about how it works.

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass location
like

```
const string searchQuery = "search:search:query=seattle&crumb=location:C://MyFolder";
Process.Start(searchQuery);
```

Comment: Is there a way not to pass an absolute location? Like to search the same locations as in start menu. What should I pass?

Comment: no, it required minimum directory letter like C: D: E: F: etc

and if you want to make search like start menu then you need to create multiple thread that search on all available directories

Comment: But there are chances "search:query=a" and "search:query=a&crumb=location:\\" could also work fine, very strange.

Comment: actually I have tried, "search:query=a&crumb=location:\\" works on Win7, but not on Win8